# как сделать в ngx-mapbox-gl двойную линию

Tags: html, angular5, mapbox

Как сделать на карте линию ,как на картинке (двойную) ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<mgl-layer
         id="lines2"
         type="line"
         [source]="{
           'type': 'geojson',
           'data': {
                     'type': 'Feature',
                     'properties': {
                       'color': colors_line2
                     },
                     'geometry': {
                         'type': 'LineString',
                         'coordinates': map_info2
                     }
                   }
         }"
         [layout]="{
           'line-join': 'round',
           'line-cap': 'round'
         }"
         [paint]="{
           'line-color': ['get', 'color'],
           'line-dasharray': [2,3],
           'line-width': 7
         }"
       >
    </mgl-layer>
```